# Cannot access svn repository url from Mac OS ver 10.10.2

Tags: macos, svn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

I have installed VisualSVN Server on a Windows PC. Other PCs on the network work well as a SVN Client and can access the repository.

However a MAC connected in the same network is not able to access the svn repository url.

The MAC has svn binaries installed in it.
Please suggest for possible reasons.

Comment: Define "not able to access". What error message are you getting?

Comment: What Subversion client do you use on MacOS? What is its version? What errors do you get?

Comment: "not able to access" --> The VisualSVN repositroy URL is not opening in the browser on MAC connected to the network. The same is accessible in different PCs connected to the network.